# Query for a specific length of time (Sql Access)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I know how to query for a specific date range, but not for a specific length of time.

So rather than looking for records where someone was employed from x date to y date, I'm looking for records where they've been employed for 5 years. Kind of funky, but does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Can't you just add X seconds/milliseconds to the start date? Most dates are stored as a number representing some small unit of time (seconds and milliseconds are the most commonly picked unit).

Comment: Well you know when they started and you know what today is if they're still employed and their end date if they're not.  So you figure out the elapsed time between that and then figure out if it's 5 years or greater. It's a single [DateDiff](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) pretty much and you can get your results in years to prevent having to do any calculations on your own to account for leap years and such.

Answer (score 3):

DateDiff just returns the difference in calendar years, so you need a custom function that uses *DateAdd* like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Then use SQL similar to:

```
Select *
From PersonTable
Where AgeSimple([EmploymentDate]) = 5
```

**For Mr. Monkey:**

Please pay attention to the in-line comments which explain in full. For example:

```
' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
```

To serve this purpose, three "awfully convoluted" lines of code are added:

```
If intYears > 0 Then
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
End If
```

To illustrate the necessity of these, please consider these two examples:

```
EmploymentDate = #2001/5/1#
Employed = DateDiff("yyyy", EmploymentDate, Date)  ' -> 15 years
Employed = AgeSimple(EmploymentDate)               ' -> 15 years

EmploymentDate = #2002/11/15#
Employed = DateDiff("yyyy", EmploymentDate, Date)  ' -> 14 years
Employed = AgeSimple(EmploymentDate)               ' -> 13 years
```

Comment: This just looks like an awfully convoluted DATEDIFF to me

Comment: I really hope your are joking. However, I've added an extended explanation to the answer which should make the purpose clear. Please study and change your down-vote to an up-vote.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information and example outputs, i know see what you are achieving with this code, have changed my vote +1

Answer (score -1):

Use the `DATEDIFF`Function

```
WHERE DATEDIFF ( yy, startdate , enddate ) = 5
```

Comment: That will just return the difference in calendar years.